# filter a list in Python, then unfilter it

Tags: python

I have a list of items in Python (v2.7 but a v2/v3 compatible solution would be nice), e.g.:

```
a = [1,6,5,None,5,None,None,1]
```

I'd like to filter out the None values, and then do something with the resulting list, e.g.:

```
b = [x for x in a if x is not None]
c = f(b)
```

Then I'd like to put the None values back in their original indices:

```
d = # ??? should give me [c[0],c[1],c[2],None,c[3],None,None,c[4]]
```

I need to pass the entire filtered list to the function f() at once. I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to do this since all of my solutions so far have been messy. Here's the cleanest one I have so far:

```
d = c
for i in range(len(a)):
    if not a[i]:
        d.insert(i, None)
```

EDIT: Fixing typo in list comprehension.

Comment: Can `f(b)` be refactored so as to accept individual elements of `b` such that `f(b) == [f(x) for x in b]`?  If so, the answer I posted (and can undelete) would be reasonable.  Otherwise, I think you'll need to cache the positions of the non-None elements so you can re-assign the new values to the list after processing.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Unfortunately not, the function f() needs to accept the entire list at once (I'm using grequests to process things in parallel inside f())

Comment: Note: since you don't make a copy (`d = c`), you're modifying `c` at the same time.

Comment: I think you mean "if x is not None"

Comment: @Istvan Chung: yes that's okay

Comment: @woot: yes indeed, fixed above, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that seems to do the trick:

```
>>> a = [1,6,5,None,5,None,None,1]
>>> b = [x for x in a if x is not None]
>>> c = [2,12,10,10,2]  # just an example
>>> 
>>> v = iter(c)
>>> [None if x is None else next(v) for x in a]
[2, 12, 10, None, 10, None, None, 2]
```

Comment: fix b, even though he put if a is not None, I think he meant if x is not None.

Comment: Nice - much cleaner than my solution above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,6,5,None,5,None,None,1]
b = [x for x in a if a is not None]
c = f(b)
d = [x if x is None else c.pop(0) for x in a]
```

Comment: @woot Well, the original question's example does so as well, so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @woot, Sure, but c looks to be used only temporarily anyway.

Comment: @IstvanChung It does, but I'm betting that was unintended since he bothered setting d.

Comment: This is actually very similar to my solution except (1) `None if x is None else ...` is what I used since you already know that `x` is `None` at that point and (2) I used an iterator to iterate over `c`, which doesn't result in poor performance from popping the front element repeatedly (remember that `lst.pop(0)` is an O(n) operation in the length of the list).

Comment: Agreed - I like this solution better than mine in the original post, but not putting c from the front seems cleaner. It's nice that this works in a single line though.

Answer (score 1):

```
j = 0
d = []
for x in a:
    if x is None:
        d.append(None)
    else:
        d.append(c[j])
        j=j+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try keeping track of where the non `None`'s go:

```
>>> def f(seq):
...     return [x+x for x in seq]
>>> a = [1,6,5,None,5,None,None,1]
>>> indices, filtered = zip(*[(i, v) for i,v in enumerate(a) if v is not None])
>>> indices
(0, 1, 2, 4, 7)
```

as before:

```
>>> filtered
(1, 6, 5, 5, 1)
>>> mapped = f(filtered)
>>> mapped
[2, 12, 10, 10, 2]
```

From here, we can make a "sparse" list from the indices and their corresponding outputs:

```
>>> unfiltered = dict(zip(indices, mapped))
>>> unfiltered
{0: 2, 1: 12, 2: 10, 4: 10, 7: 2}
```

which we can then expand into a non-sparse version by Checking each index position:

```
>>> result = [unfiltered.get(i) for i in range(len(a))]
>>> result
[2, 12, 10, None, 10, None, None, 2]
```